# Backbone view removes other instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Upon testing out backbone.js I encountered a problem.
How would i create a generalized view that can be used multiple times on a page?

My current implementation creates a simple `FooControls` view used in two other by using Jquery's `append`.

However it ends up only beeing used and added to the DOM in last view.

JSBin, reproducing my problem.
http://jsbin.com/kopos/1/edit
(The red square represents the `FooControls`view, shouldn't there be two red squares?)

How would i go about creating a view that can be used multiple times on a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead (see [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/yokuwomu/1/edit)):

```
var FooControls = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'foo-control'
});
var ScreenView = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'screen',
    render: function() {
        var fooOne = new FooControls();
        this.$el.append(fooOne.$el);
    }
});
var FileView = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'files',
    render: function() {
        var fooTwo = new FooControls();
        this.$el.append(fooTwo.$el);
    }
});

var screenInstance = new ScreenView();
var fileInstance = new FileView();
screenInstance.render();
fileInstance.render();
$('#wrapper').append(screenInstance.$el);
$('#wrapper').append(fileInstance.$el);
```

Using `className` gets you the same functionality you seemed to be looking for, without the rendering problems.

By the way, I would start to optimize/refactor this as follows (some of this is just personal preference):

```
var FooControls = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'foo-control'
});
var ScreenView = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'screen',
    render: function() {
        var fooOne = new FooControls();
        this.$el.append(fooOne.$el);
        return this;
    }
});
var FileView = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'files',
    render: function() {
        var fooTwo = new FooControls();
        this.$el.append(fooTwo.$el);
        return this;
    }
});

var screenInstance = new ScreenView(),
    fileInstance = new FileView();

$('#wrapper')
  .append(screenInstance.render().$el);
  .append(fileInstance.render().$el);
```

Comment: Any idea what the cause of this is? Is it intended behaviour when using the `el` member?